# C# MVC validation using data annotations (database first)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

So I have an API that has a controller `post` action like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Model m){
  if(!ModelState.IsValid){
    return ApiRequest.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
  }
}
```

And here is my model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
public partial class MyModel {

  private sealed class Metadata {

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Sample error msg.")]
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    // ...other fields and foreign key fields here
  }

}
```

As I stated on my title, I am using database first which is why I created a `partial` class since my models are auto-generated.

The problem is when a validation error occurs the result JSON of error messages looks like this:

```
{
  e.Field1: "Error msg here...",
  e.Field2: "Error msg here...",
  e.DateField: "An error occurred" //This happens for any date type field even though i've specified an error message
  e: ["An error occurred", "An error occurred"] //This happens for the foreign key fields i.e. AnotherModelID, I got 2 which is why I think it has two error messages also
}
```

First what I want here is to remove the `e` prefix on the `keys` of the JSON result. Then why is the error `An error occurred` being returned even though I've put an error message explicitly? And also why does the foreign key fields doesn't display just the prefix `e`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Upon more research I think in the case where the error `key` is only the letter `e` instead of the `e.FieldName` happens when the data type of the field in question is `int`. I've tested a non-foreign key int field and it also adds to the error under the "e only" key.

Comment: You should use the different class like ViewModel instead of using Domain Class directly in your controller.

Comment: Sorry @Saadi can you give a sample?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc